# Add spaces within single line comment block in WebStorm

Tags: css, comments, webstorm

When hitting <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + /</kbd> in CSS files, or in any files that only support comment block syntax, I would like WebStorm to add spaces within that block if it is on a single line, which is not the case by default. 
I just can't find any options in CSS code style to achieve this.

```
My css comment
```

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + /</kbd> gives this :

```
/*My css comment*/
```

What do I want :

```
/* My css comment */
```

Comment: @MrLister Thanks indeed ! Edited question.

Answer (score 2):

Please vote for [WEB-30716](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30716) to be notified on any progress with this feature

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, What I did as a workaround was create a AutoHotKey Script

```
:*b:[/css]::
    Send, /* DESC */
return
```

You can now double-click DESC and edit it.

Comment: Well... if he want snippet for comment .. then it's better to just use built-in Live Templates functionality. Here OP already has some text .. which he wants to convert into a comment (surround with) using standard shortcut. (P.S. Surround kind of Live Template is also available .. but it's hard to compare with actual Comment shortcut in convenience).